# If $\Phi \vdash \phi \to \psi$, show that $\Phi, \phi, \neg\psi$ is inconsistent.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

> If $\Phi \vdash \phi \to \psi$, show that $\Phi, \phi, \neg\psi$ is inconsistent.

I am stuck on my proof.

> Assume that $\Phi \vdash \phi \to \psi$. Then $\Phi, \neg(\phi \to \psi)$ is inconsistent or $\Phi, \phi \wedge \neg \psi$ is inconsistent. Then $\sigma(\phi \wedge \neg \psi) = F$.

I am not sure where to go from here since the falsity can be made in three ways and I just wanted one way, where $\sigma(\phi)=\sigma(\neg\psi)=F$.

Comment: Can't you just use the contrapositive to show $\phi\implies \psi$ is equivalent to $\neg\psi\implies\neg\phi$? Then you have both $\phi$ and $\neg\phi$ as theorems.

Comment: @JohnDouma This is what I got: Assume that $\Phi, \phi, \neg \psi$ is consistent. Then $\sigma(\phi) = \sigma(\neg \psi) = T$. Then $\sigma(\phi \wedge \neg \psi) = T$ or $\sigma(\neg (\phi \to \psi)) = T$. Then $\Phi, \neg (\phi \to \psi)$ is consistent. If $\Phi \vdash \phi \to \psi$, then $\Phi, \neg(\phi \to \psi)$ is inconsistent, which forms a contradiction. How is this?

Comment: I don't understand why you aren't done after $\sigma(\neg (\phi \to \psi)) = T$ because you have a statement and its negative both true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the deduction theorem.

$\Phi\vdash \phi\to\psi$, so $\Phi,\phi\vdash\psi$.  Hence $\Phi,\phi,\lnot\psi$ syntactically entails both $\psi$ (coming from $\Phi,\phi$) and $\lnot\psi$ (from $\lnot\psi\vdash\lnot\psi$), so is inconsistent.

Or with valuations:
Let $v$ be a valuation that assigns $\top$ to all of $\Phi,\phi,\lnot\psi$.  From $\Phi\vdash\phi\to\psi$, we have $v(\phi\to\psi)=\top$.  Also, by supposition $v(\phi)=\top$, so we must have $v(\psi)=\top$, contradicting $v(\lnot\psi)=\top$.

Comment: (That's using modus ponens at the first step, not the deduction theorem!)

Comment: It is deduction theorem: $\Phi\vdash p\to q$ iff $\Phi,p\vdash q$.  Modus ponens is $\phi,\phi\to\psi\vdash\psi$.

Comment: No, the label "deduction theory" is standardly used just for the direction if $\Phi,p\vdash q$ then  $\Phi \vdash p \to q$.

Comment: (The other direction relies on the modus ponens inference taking us from $\Phi \vdash p \to q$ and the triviality $\Phi, p \vdash p$ to $\Phi, p \vdash q$.)

Answer (score 2):

> Assume that $\Phi \vdash \phi \to \psi$. Then $\Phi, \neg(\phi \to \psi)$ is inconsistent or $\Phi, \phi \wedge \neg \psi$ is inconsistent.

If you are allowed to use those substitution equivalences, you're done.

When $\{x, y\land z\}$ is inconsistent, so too $\{x,y,z\}$ is inconsistent, because $\nu(y\land z)=\mathrm T$ iff $\nu(y)\land\mathrm T$ and $\nu(z)\land\mathrm T$.

So $\{x, y, z\}$ cannot be satisfied by any evaluation exactly when $\{x, y\land z\}$ cannot be satisfied.

---

...

---

But more simply, use deduction theorem: When $\Phi\vdash \phi\to \psi$, then we may infer that $\Phi, \phi\vdash \psi$ and so...