# If $\Phi, \phi, \neg\psi$ is inconsistent, show that $\Phi \vdash \phi \to \psi$.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

> If $\Phi, \phi, \neg\psi$ is inconsistent, show that $\Phi \vdash \phi \to \psi$.

What I have so far:

If $\Phi, \phi, \neg\psi$ is inconsistent, then $\Phi, \phi \vdash \psi$. Then by deduction, $\Phi \vdash \phi \to \psi$.

> I am not sure what this means though. Where did $\Phi, \phi \vdash \psi$ come from? Does this also mean that $\Phi, \neg\psi \vdash \neg\phi$?

Comment: What is the definition of "inconsistent"? Usually there is a "syntactic" one and a "semantic" one. Also, what does $\vdash$ mean? Usually, it expresses the notion of derivability in some deductive system. Which one are you using? Finally, are you entitled to use soundness and/or completeness theorem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If $\Phi \vdash \phi \to \psi$, show that $\Phi, \phi, \neg\psi$ is inconsistent.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2986448/if-phi-vdash-phi-to-psi-show-that-phi-phi-neg-psi-is-inconsistent)

Comment: Didn't you ask this question and accept the answer two days ago?

Comment: @JohnDouma Well, that is the *converse* of this.  But, yes, the same reasoning skills should apply.

Comment: As per [your previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2987985/if-both-phi-neg-phi-and-phi-psi-are-inconsistent-then-phi-vdash-n) it is necessary to specify the context of the question : is the def of *consistency* the "syntactical" one ? i.e. related to $\vdash$ ?

Comment: If so, you have to start from the definition of $\vdash$ in order to answer to the question : "Where did $\Phi, \phi ⊢ \psi$ come from ?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am not sure what this means though. Where did $Φ,ϕ⊢ψ$ come from?

Saying that the statements $\Phi, \phi,\neg \psi$ are inconsistent, means that they cannot be mutually satisfied (there is no valuation that allows the three statements to all be true).   Therefore if they are inconsistent, then any valuation that can satisfy both $\Phi$ and $\phi$, cannot also satisfy $\neg\psi$ .   In bivalued logic this means the evaluation must satisfy $\psi$, so we say $\Phi$ and $\phi$ entail $\psi$.   Ie: $\Phi, \phi\vDash \psi$ .

> Does this also mean that $Φ,¬ψ\vdash ¬ϕ$?

Yes.   For the same reasons.   We can likewise use deduction to infer that $\Phi\vDash \neg\psi\to\neg\phi$ .

---

(Also note that we should be using $\vDash$ for the entailment because we are discussing semantics when talking about consistency.)